# Jest React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs

I can't test this simple react container. Documetation doesn't help me...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import {loadBoards} from '../../actions/boardJS'
import Board from '../../components/Board/Board'

class BoardContainer extends Component {
  getBoards() {
    fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_DEV_API_URL + `todo_lists`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.props.dispatch(loadBoards(data))
        })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getBoards()
  }

  render() {
    return <Board/>

  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    boards: state.boards
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BoardContainer)
```

How can i test mapStateToProps or componentDidMount? I need simple working example. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried exactly? And what doesn't work? What do you want the test to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading [this](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/04/testing-strategies-for-react-and-redux/) article. It explains really well how to test redux-connected components. 
In gist, they use a real store instance for each test and populate it with data.

Comment: could you extend your answer with more text and some examples? link provides good information but sometimes links become broken. so when answer just provide a link it will become useless some day. But if you add few paragraphs it will still be useful then.